# Перенесёные вопросы в очереди первых сообщений

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок, аудит

Только что в очереди проверки первых сообщений попался перенесённый вопрос.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/209566

Поскольку вопрос уже был перенесён модератором, я нажал кнопку "Действия не требуются", т.к. в действительности действия уже не требуются - ведь Nofate же перенёс сообщение. Однако это оказалось ловушкой, что на мой взгляд выглядит как сбой системы - подобные вопросы либо вовсе не должны появляться в очереди, либо надпись "перенесён" должна быть скрыта.

Answer (score 3):

Подобный дефект уже описан на MSE: [Security Audit: First post, what was the proper reaction?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168033/339911)

Но править его что-то не спешат, видимо из-за того, что ситуация довольно редкая, а стало быть, затрагивает слишком малый процент участников. Стоит заметить, что [аналогичную ситуацию](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163747/339911), но с вопросами, закрытыми как дубликат, пофиксили. Ведь дубликаты появляются существенно чаще, нежели перенесённые вопросы.